# Internal Server ErrorBEA-380001

Tags: php, webservice

Estimados,

Estoy intentado consumir un WS desde una aplicación PHP.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
$lib_nusoap='libs/nusoap/nusoap.php';
require_once($lib_nusoap);
$all_info = array();
$client = new nusoap_client('localhost:7001/miservicio/servicio?WSDL', true);
$all_info[]=$client->call('buscaAlumnoByRut', array("rut"=>"12345678"));
$err = $client->getError();
var_dump($all_info);
```

y la respuesta es: Internal Server ErrorBEA-380001

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmloap.og/soap/enelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>BEA-380001: Internal Server Error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wi/sb/contex">
               <con:errorCode>BEA-380001</con:errorCode>
               <con:reason>Internal Server Error</con:reason>
               <con:location>
                  <con:node>RouteTo_DatosBasicosBS</con:node>
                  <con:path>response-pipeline</con:path>
               </con:location>
            </con:fault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Quedo atento!

Comment: Ese código de error lo genera el servidor al que conectas. Si fuera un problema de comunicaciones o similar no te saldría por pantalla, se quedaría en `$client->getError()`. ¿Has probado a usar los servicios web con un cliente como SoapUI o similar?

Comment: Cuando dices error de comunicaciones te refieres a que estoy llegando a la maquina donde se encuentra el servicio, pero se produce un error al ejecutar la llamada?

Comment: Todo lo contrario, pienso que no es un error de comunicaciones (pero no tengo experiencia en `nusoap` para estar seguro). Prueba mi código, te informará detalladamente de todo lo que está pasando durante la ejecución del servicio web, nos ayudará a solucionar tu problema gracias a la información de depuración que proporciona.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría hacerlo usando el [cliente SOAP](http://php.net/SoapClient) que ofrece PHP y no haciendo uso de `nusoap` (¿no ha quedado obsoleta?).

Ejemplo de uso:

```
try {
  $cliente = @new SoapClient(
    'http://localhost:7001/miservicio/servicio?WSDL',
    [
      'exceptions' => 1,
      'trace' => 1,
    ]
  );
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
  echo "<p>Datos de la excepción:</p>\n";
  var_dump($e);
  exit();
}
/* Mostramos datos de depuración */
echo "<p>Funciones:</p>\n";
var_dump($cliente->__getFunctions());
echo "<p>Tipos de datos:</p>\n";
var_dump($cliente->__getTypes());
try {
  $resultado = $cliente->__call(
    'buscaAlumnoByRut',
    [
      'rut' => '12345678',
    ]
  );
  echo "<p>Resultado:</p>\n";
  var_dump($resultado);
  echo "<p>Detalles de la petición:</p>\n";
  var_dump($cliente->__getLastRequest());
  echo "<p>Detalles de la respuesta:</p>\n";
  var_dump($cliente->__getLastResponse());
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
  echo "<p>Detalles de la petición:</p>\n";
  var_dump($cliente->__getLastRequest());
  echo "<p>Datos de la excepción:</p>\n";
  var_dump($e);
  exit();
}
```

Con este código te quedará claro qué genera qué código. Mi suposición es que no se produce ninguna excepción por culpa de problemas de comunicaciones y que el problema puede estar devolviéndolo el servicio web al que te conectas.

Con lo que te devuelva la ejecución de este código podré ayudarte a depurar mejor qué está pasando. No me vale con lo que muestra el navegador, necesitaría el contenido HTML ya que `var_dump` podría contener datos con etiquetas XML que serían interpretadas por el navegador como parte del contenido de la página.